# How to get a specific object if using input from user

Tags: python, loops, object

I've made Class Dog and I created the objects through user input. Now I'm trying to choose a specific Dog that was made but I'm not sure how to get that objects information.

I've attempted looping through the objects but they're not iterable. I'm only aware of how to get information when declaring the objects e.g. d1 = Dog("Sam", 5, "Labrador) print(d1.name). However I believe this situation would be different. The red line is where I am attempting to get a specific dog's data. Let's say the user is attempting to get the dog "Sam"'s information. How would you get it?

```
# let's make a dog class
dog_list = ["labrador", "beagle", "poodle", "husky"]  # global variable


class Dog:
    obj_instances = []
    # attributes of the class

    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
        # add all instances to this list
        self.obj_instances.append(self.name)

    # string representation of the object
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}({self.age}) is a {self.breed}"

    # find dog's favorite toy
    def favorite_toy(self):
        favorite_toy = None
        # here we have a list of toys
        toy_list = ["ball", "squeaky bone", "frisbee", "pillow"]
        dog_counter = 0

        # go through each type of dog until we match the breed of our dog object
        # then we match the position of the breed to the position of the toy
        for dogType in dog_list:
            if self.breed == dogType:
                favorite_toy = toy_list[dog_counter]
                break
            else:
                favorite_toy = "unknown"
            dog_counter = dog_counter + 1

        return f"{self.name}'s favorite toy is {favorite_toy}."


# d1 = Dog("Millard", 6, "labrador")
# print(d1.name)
print("Let's add 3 dogs to our Dog class.")
dog_entry = 0
while dog_entry < 2:
    dog_name = input("What is your dog's name?\n")
    dog_age = input("What is your dog's age?\n")
    dog_breed = input("What is your dog's breed?\n").lower()
    Dog(dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed)
    dog_entry = dog_entry + 1

# Let's check the dogs we added
print(f"Current instances: {Dog.obj_instances}")
for x in Dog:
    print(x)
# Let's ask the user to tell us which dog they'd like to know more about
confirmation = input("Would you like to know more about one of these dogs? (y/n)\n").lower()
dog_observed = None
if confirmation[0] == "y":
    dog_observed = input("Which dog are you interested in knowing more about?\n")
    # Let's show them that dog's information
    count = 0
    for dogs in Dog.obj_instances:
        if Dog.obj_instances[count] == dog_observed:
            print("Found dog") # how to get that objects information without object !!!!!!!!!!!
            break
        count = count + 1
else:
    print("Thanks for coming. Have a good day.")
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Usually, you don't make a class responsible for collecting all instances of the class in a single list. If you need such a list, manage it yourself *outside* the class.

Comment: I've removed the images and pasted the code instead @buran

Answer (score 0):

You can throw the dogs themself into the `obj_instances` list by changing:

`self.obj_instances.append(self.name)` to `self.obj_instances.append(self)`

now you have a list filled with your created dogs.
then later on you can iterate thru the dogs and check if a `dog.name` is same as your input:

```
if confirmation[0] == "y":
    dog_observed = input("Which dog are you interested in knowing more about?\n")
    # Let's show them that dog's information
    
    for dogs in Dog.obj_instances:
        if dogs.name == dog_observed:
            print("Found dog")  
            current_dog = dogs
            print(current_dog.name)
            print(current_dog.age)
            print(current_dog.breed)
```